# How to update web view width after device rotation in objective c?

Tags: ios, webview

When I first load the web view its frame is correct but when I rotate the device, its width is not update.
For instance, if the view was portrait and I rotate it in landscape the web view frame is not cover the whole view.

**Loading web view**

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self loadWebView];
}

-(void) loadWebView {
    UIWebView *webView;

    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.frame];

    NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",html_header_with_files,DetailsHtml,HTML_FOOTER];

    [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
}
```

---

**First try:**
I added a notification to realize the rotation

```
- (void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Above code did not solve the problem.

---

**Second try**

```
- (void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
    [self loadWebView];
}
```

Above code did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The view has to be added with auto layout so that it gets laid out properly in all devices with both orientation.

You need to create an extension of UIView and add the below method to make it a reusable code. You can also add the method in the same class if you are not going to use this method anywhere else.

```
- (void)addSubView:(UIView *)subView belowView:(UIView *)belowView inSuperView:(UIView *)superView {
        [superView addSubview:subView];

        [superView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:superView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
        [superView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:superView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
        [superView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:superView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
        if (nil == belowView) {
            [superView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:superView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
        } else {
            [superView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:belowView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
        }
    }
```

Then you need to call the above method like

```
[self addSubView:webView belowView:nil inSuperView:self.view];
```

**Note:**

To know more about auto-layout you can follow the tutorial

https://www.raywenderlich.com/443-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-11-getting-started

Also its better to start writing your app with swift rather than continuing objective-c even if some of your codebase is already in objective-c. A tutorial to make obj-c and swift inter operability can be seen in below link

https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/swift-and-objective-c-interoperability-2add8e6d6887

Comment: Thanks a lot, especially for your helpful advices.

Comment: Please accept and upvote the answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: I upvoted it but I haven't test it yet. I'll accept it as soon as I test it.

Comment: If you find this answer helpful, can you please Accept as answer. It will help to improve my SO rating